# Email calling from another function in codeigniter | PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, passwords, recovery

I am calling a function (mail) from another function (forget) to send mail by passing argument like $to & $msg. but every time i run the code it says that "cant load the email library" but when i run the same code without calling of function it smoothly send the mail.

```
public function forget(){
  $this->load->library('session');
  $this->load->helper('form');
  $this->load->database();
  $this->load->model('Session_eg_model');
  $to=$this->input->post('email');
  $otp=mt_rand(100000, 999999);
  $response=$this->Session_eg_model->forget_pass($to,$otp);
  if($response==101){
    echo "Enter correct mail";
  }
  else{
    $msg="Use this new password ".$otp." to login ";
     $this->mail($to,$msg);
    $this->load->view('session_pass_view');
  }
}

public function mail($to,$msg){
    $config = Array(
'protocol' => 'smtp',
'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
'smtp_port' => 465,
'smtp_user' => '****@gmail.com',
'smtp_pass' => '********',
'mailtype' => 'html',
'charset' => 'iso-8859-1',
'wordwrap' => TRUE
    );

  $this->load->library('email', $config);
  $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
  $this->email->from('prateek.singhglavvdn@gmail.com', 'prateek');
  $this->email->to($to);
  $this->email->subject('password recovery');
  $this->email->message($msg);
  $this->email->send();
}
```

Comment: is it already loaded in your `config.php` file?

Comment: No, but i am loading it in
$this->load->library('email',$config);

Comment: where you have called function( mail ) from function  forget

Comment: i edited it,,, i am calling mail() function in forget() function and  when somebody press the "forget password" button in the view it ask for email and then forget() function called